# Rewrite Rule returns 500 internal server error litespeed

Tags: apache, server, url-rewriting, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

how are you ? Today I'm with this problem that I cannot solve.

I created an instance to which I associated a docker container using cyberpanel, so far so good since if I enter the URL of the instance including the port I can use the app correctly. Now, I am trying to use the main domain of the instance as if it were the domain with the port and for this I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:9000/$1 [P,L]
```

When doing this my app is returning an error code 500.

Also, I tried to add in the OpenLiteSpeed panel (in the corresponding virtualhost) an "External App" that points to the url with the port.

[image]

I am using cloudflare also to reach the instances.

Some clue ? Thank you very much and have a good day / night

Answer (score 0):

the `htpp://127.0.0.1:8000` way only works for LiteSpeed Enterprise

for OpenLiteSpeed , you need to create the external app , and then use that name

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://StrapiBackend/$1 [P,L]
```